# Where does Zeitgeist store its data?

Tags: user-data, zeitgeist

I want to move Zeitgeist data for a user from one computer to another. He uses Gnome Activity Journal, and it would be nice to move his history.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type this command in a terminal:

> nautilus ~/.local/share/zeitgeist

This is the zeitgeist directory where it stores the data.

Comment: Odd that you would suggest opening up a terminal to type a command to open up nautilus. Wouldn't it make more sense to just list the directory?

Comment: I found it much easier to enter a simple command instead of  directing him into directories and telling to look into hidden files.

Comment: @Gaurav That's a good point. In Nautilus, I believe you can use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+L and then type in the location like ~/.local/share/zeitgeist to get there immediately.

Comment: @Firefeather Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't think of this way, would keep in mind next time.

Comment: @Gaurav You're sure welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this link:

http://live.gnome.org/Zeitgeist/Blueprint/DatabaseMigrationAndBackup

Thanks!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.